# Shutdown Jetty - ShutdownHandler vs stop()

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, shutdown

There are several questions about shuting down Jetty here on SO but they are almost 10 years old and do not fully cover my question.

I have an embedded Jetty server in my application and want to shutdown the server from inside of the application.
So far, I figured out several ways to do this:

```
ShutdownHandler shutdownHandler = new ShutdownHandler("shutdownToken");
server.setHandler(new HandlerList(shutdownHandler));
shutdownHandler.sendShutdown();
```

```
server.stop();
```

What is the difference between these thow approaches? I could not find a suitable answer in the Jetty documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ShutdownHandler` exists to allow an HTTP request to shutdown the server if the request contains the correct password/token to initiate the shutdown.

Not a recommended solution for a server that is publicly accessible on the internet.

`server.stop()` is a good solution, but you cannot use that method from a thread that the server manages.

That's why `ShutdownHandler` schedules the `server.stop()` that it uses on another thread that the Server isn't managing.

**Recommended Setup**

1. create a password/token for shutdown
2. use the `ShutdownMonitor` to listen on localhost for a command to shutdown, this command has a password/token that must be provided that authorizes the shutdown.
3. setup `Server.setStopTimeout(long)` to allow graceful timeout of server components.
4. setup `StatisticsHandler` on the server handler tree (at the start) to track active connections/requests for the graceful shutdown to wait for active requests to finish before stop is initiated.

When it's time to shutdown your server, you now have 2 options.

1. send SIGHUP signal to process
2. send `shutdown` command to process

**How jetty-home's start.jar works with this recommended setup**

The provided `bin/jetty.sh` in the `jetty-home` distribution will use essentially the following set of commands.

```sh
$ cd /path/to/myjettybase
$ java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --stop
```

The configured `${jetty.base}` will contain the various STOP configuration needed to know how to stop the server (STOP_HOST, STOP_PORT, STOP_KEY, STOP_WAIT).

Comment: Thank you for this, very helpful and I wouldn't have known about ShutdownMonitor except for this post. I can't find Jetty documentation that shows how to do proper shutdown, despite the existence of this class, which I find odd. The only way I can figure out how to use the ShutdownMonitor is by looking at the source. Again, odd.
Do you know why both ShutdownHandler and ShutdownMonitor both exist? And when to use one over the other?